# Count negative values in a PHP array

Tags: php

I have an array which looks something like this:

```
array(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I would like to count the number of negative numbers only. I can't spot where it says how to do this in the manual, is there no function to do this? Do I have to create a loop to go through the array manually?

Comment: Yes, there's no `count_negative_numbers_in_array` function build in. You'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: And now, seriously. Why do people try to overcomplicate things by calling several built-in functions? Just because that they have _golden_ name "built-in"?

Comment: @PLB Sure, *combining* several built-in methods will of course solve the problem... :P

Comment: @deceze I was just kidding. ;) btw, people should be missing something like [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/R8bsTE) (especially if they come from .net).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I have to create a loop to go through the array manually?

Yes, you have to do it manually by easily doing:

```
function count_negatives(array $array) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $x)
        if ($x < 0) $i++;
    return $i;
}
```

At the end of the script `$i` will contain the number of negative numbers.

Comment: The Op knows that, he asked for build in functionality. So answer is *there is None*.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, and saves me a bit of typing too :) Nice. Thank you Jeffery

Answer (score 1):

I should use this:

```
$array = array(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4);

function negative($int) {
     return ($int < 0);
}

var_dump(count(array_filter($array, "negative")));
```

Comment: i find this solution more elegant and still readable (event with the use a lambda function inside the `array_filter`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_filter`

```
function neg($var){
    if($var < 0){
        return $var;
    }        
}

$array1 = array(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
print count(array_filter($array1, "neg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_filter http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

```
function isnegative($value){
    return is_numeric($value) && $value < 0;
}

$arr = array_filter(array(-1,2,3,-4), 'isnegative');

echo length($arr);
```

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$aValues = array(1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3, 0);
echo sizeof(array_filter($aValues, create_function('$v', 'return $v < 0;')));
```